# JAVA Socket Accept hangs

Tags: java, android, serversocket

Below code hangs does not go past beyond below messages and is hanging at socket.accept(). 
Its part of an android app and INTERNET permissions are already added to manifest. Tried putting accept in while(true) loop...but that did not work:

**09-23 15:55:43.737 24079-25436: Trying to open port 5556...
09-23 15:55:43.739 24079-25436: >>> Opening Port : 5556**

```js
    private Socket socket = null;
    private ServerSocket server = null;

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";


    public boolean openPort(String host , int port){

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG , "Error initializing serverSocket: " , e);
        }

        Log.e(TAG , ">>> Opening Port : " + port);

        boolean bmsg = false;

        try {
                socket = server.accept();
                Log.e(TAG , ">>> Opened Port : " + port);

                return true;
        } catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "Error opening port: ", e);
            return bmsg;
        } catch(SecurityException s){
            Log.e(TAG, "sError opening port: ", s);
            return bmsg;

        } catch(IllegalBlockingModeException b){
            Log.e(TAG, "bError opening port: ", b);
            return bmsg;
        }
    }
```

Above class is being called from below async task on button click:

```js
private class openPort extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        Log.i(TAG , "Trying to open port 5556...");
        //host is localhost
        //port is 5556
        OpenClosePort ocp = new OpenClosePort();
        ocp.openPort(host , port);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you run it in main thread?

Comment: it's being called from Async code block... is it suppose to be in a separate thread?

Comment: Let me see that please. Because if you run it in async block, hanging must not happen.

Comment: Edited the code snippet...

Comment: remove "TextView txtPortNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PortNumber);" from doInBackground.

Comment: reduced async block to the one in snippet...still same issue

Comment: What is `OpenClosePort`? Code is incomplete.